# TypeDoc error when `@types/___` differs from package

Tags: typescript, definitelytyped, typedoc

A recent update to the `@types/ndarray` package ([#52505](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/pull/52505)) introduced a distinction between the `ndarray` function and the `NdArray` return type. My TypeScript code compiles and runs fine with this change, no problem there. But I am running into trouble when trying to use TypeDoc with functions that take NdArray objects as parameters:

```
Error: node_modules/@types/get-pixels/index.d.ts:8:10 - error TS2305: Module '"ndarray"' has no exported member 'NdArray'.

8 import { NdArray } from "ndarray";
           ~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@types/ndarray-ops/index.d.ts:6:10 - error TS2305: Module '"ndarray"' has no exported member 'NdArray'.

6 import { NdArray } from "ndarray";
           ~~~~~~~

Error: node_modules/@types/save-pixels/index.d.ts:8:15 - error TS2305: Module '"ndarray"' has no exported member 'NdArray'.

8 import { NdArray } from "ndarray";
                ~~~~~~~
```

My first guess was to replace these lines in the type packages with `import type` instead of `import`, but no change there. It appears that Typedoc is looking for this export in the actual ndarray package, when it only exists in `@types/ndarray`. You can reproduce this error pretty quickly by cloning the [ndarray-pixels](https://github.com/donmccurdy/ndarray-pixels) repository, running `yarn upgrade-interactive --latest`, and then running `yarn docs`.

Is this something I need to configure TypeDoc for? Is it a bug in TypeDoc, the DefinitelyTyped definitions, or something else? I'm not understanding whether an actual export needs to exist when only `import type` is being used.

Related discussion on [DefinitelyTyped repository](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/discussions/54710).

Comment: Adding `skipLibCheck` to your compiler options in your tsconfig will probably let you ignore this error

Comment: Thanks, this did work –  is it possible to skip the check for typedoc but not for actual builds?

Comment: You can point typedoc to a custom tsconfig that extends from your normal one